# Swift 3 ViewController with generics type and UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, generics

I'm trying to create a VC with generic type like this:

```
class SearchViewController<T>: UIViewControlle {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var delegate: SearchViewControllerDelegate?
    fileprivate var dataArray: [T] = []

...
 }

extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return showAddRow ? 1 : dataArray.count

    }
}
```

But I get this error :

> Non-'@objc' method 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' does not
>   satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

I've tried to the `@objc method` like this :

> ```
> @objc(tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)
> ```

but it didn't worked. What I've missed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need declare all protocol for tableView ..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
private func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at UITableViewDataSource protocol in Swift :
you will notice that

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

is non-optional method, so you must declare its to make your code works!
(Same with `UITableViewDelegate`)

```
public protocol UITableViewDataSource : NSObjectProtocol {


    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int


    // Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
    // Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell


    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int // Default is 1 if not implemented


    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?


    // Editing

    // Individual rows can opt out of having the -editing property set for them. If not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable.
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool


    // Moving/reordering

    // Allows the reorder accessory view to optionally be shown for a particular row. By default, the reorder control will be shown only if the datasource implements -tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool


    // Index

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? // return list of section titles to display in section index view (e.g. "ABCD...Z#")

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int // tell table which section corresponds to section title/index (e.g. "B",1))


    // Data manipulation - insert and delete support

    // After a row has the minus or plus button invoked (based on the UITableViewCellEditingStyle for the cell), the dataSource must commit the change
    // Not called for edit actions using UITableViewRowAction - the action's handler will be invoked instead
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)


    // Data manipulation - reorder / moving support

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
}
```